# How to measure a laser diode's Wavelength

Tags: lasers, metrology

I have some laser diodes. I want to know how to measure the wavelength of laser diodes ranging from visible to near infrared? (300 nm to 1100 nm)

What type of instrument/meter do I need to use? spectrometer, spectrophotometer, wavelength meter, reflectometer, oscilloscope or what and how?

Comment: This question recently came up on physics.SE, and Floris's answer to the question is quite excellent.  [How to measure the wavelength of a laser pointer?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/191189/how-to-measure-the-wavelength-of-a-laser-pointer)

Comment: What sort of resolution do you need?  (a few nm?)  I'm think a wave-meter will be over kill for you. (and too expensive)  A spectrometer would be fine.  Or as Chris M. links to above get a diffraction grating, measure the angle and do the math.

Answer (score 4):

You want a wavelength meter if you have one or otherwise a spectrometer.  In more detail:

- A **wavelength meter** uses an interferometer to measure wavelength.  It can measure wavelengths very accurately.
- A **spectrometer** measures a spectrum, that is intensity *vs* wavelength.  The wavelength at the peak intensity is what you are looking for.
- A **spectrophotometer** is used to measure the transmission spectrum of some material.  This is not what you want.
- A **reflectometer** measures reflectivity.  Again, not what you want.
- **Oscilloscopes** measure electrical voltage *vs* time.    Again, not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for help.Do you know any basic entry level  Wavelength meter model # ?.

Comment: Good sources for optical equipment like this are newport.com and thorlabs.com.  If there is an inexpensive version, then edmundoptics.com will likely sell it.